# LastFullWeek starting with monday in crystal reports

Tags: date, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

When using LastFullWeek i get the last Sunday - Saturday week, but for my reports i want the last Monday - Sunday week.
Is there any simple way to get this behaviour, or do I have to write my own function for it (which isn't that hard, but unconvenient for such a common date span.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

custom function:

```
//LastFullWeekEx
Function (DateVar date, Optional NumberVar firstDayOfWeek := crSunday)
  (date - DayOfWeek(date, firstDayOfWeek)) - 6 TO (date - DayOfWeek(date, firstDayOfWeek))
```

usage:

```
// use with non-volatile DataDate and Sunday
{TABLE.DATE} IN LastFullWeekEx(DataDate)

// use with non-volatile DataDate and Monday
{TABLE.DATE} IN LastFullWeekEx(DataDate, crMonday)
```

testing:

```
// should return True
( Minimum(LastFullWeek) = Minimum(LastFullWeekEx(DataDate, crSunday)) ) AND
( Maximum(LastFullWeek) = Maximum(LastFullWeekEx(DataDate, crSunday)) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

> {DATE} in LastFullWeek

use the form

> {DATE}-1 in LastFullWeek

Comment: This doesn't work for the same reason the solution given by zachstagrammer doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The code, if no better answer comes along, for others who find this question through the search engine:

```
{DATE} >= currentdate - dayofweek(currentdate, crMonday) - 6 AND
{DATE} <  currentdate - dayofweek(currentdate, crMonday) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no other choice than to use a custom formule as Crystal Reports uses fixed week settings (US). So a week is Sunday to Saturday and DayOfWeek starts with Sunday (value/index 1).

Comment: DayOfWeek can simply be made to start the week on other weekdays by using `DayOfWeek (date, firstDayOfWeek)`. I was hoping there was a similar solution to my LastFullWeek problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Add +1 to LastFullWeek min and max:**

```
DateVar Start := Minimum(LastFullWeek)+1; //Monday
DateVar End := Maximum(LastFullWeek)+1;   //Sunday
```

**Edit:** Since `LastFullWeek` always takes Sunday as the first day of the week, we need to check if the current day is Sunday.  If so, we need to subtract a week:

```
// Check if the current day is Sunday
IF (DAYOFWEEK(CurrentDate) = 1)
THEN (
    Start := Start - 7;
    End := End - 7
);
```

---

***Example: Date range to string***

```
StringVar LastWeekRange := ToText(Start) + " - " + ToText(End);

LastWeekRange;
```

Return example: "MM/DD/YYYY - MM/DD/YYYY"

---

***Example: Selecting all dates within date range***

```
{datefield} >= Start and {datefield} <= End;
```

Comment: I don't think that works:

If Today = Sunday 29th March 2020

Then LastFullWeekBasedOnSunday = 22 March to 28 March

and your solution would return 23 March to 29 March.

But LastFullWeekBasedOnMonday should be 16 March to 22 March

Comment: @dougwoodrow  You are correct.  I have edited my answer to resolve this issue.